# Secure connection failed Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

My magento adminpanel works perfectly fine with HTTPS except a "edit/section/payment/key/session_code", I've been trying to debug it but the error page doesn't appear as well on this page.

```
http://screencast.com/t/by04q6f5cGlc
```

I want to know how can I find the problem with this page, any help will be highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you did move your site from another server you need to delete the cash files, and if you have a reside cash try to disable it.
Second open the Apache log file to see if there is something to follow in that area.
At the end I think there is conflict between your payment SSL certificate and the SSL from your store, if you have an external payment gateway .
Best.

Comment: I've deleted cache files, I've not moved the server, I tried disable payment modules but didn't work

Comment: So do you use custom payment modules or third party extensions??